# How to align label vetically without using max-width?

Tags: html, css

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udyzyoq6/

- green frame is what I want to achieve
- red frame is failing example

HTML (for failing example):

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <label class="label">
    Long label text, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS (for failing example):

```
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.square {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

I DON'T want to set `max-width` on label - I just want it to automatically use all available space of `.parent` (300px-15px). In my example, if I wont set `max-width` on label then long text breaks layout (as in red frame).

---

Edit: I don't want to set any fixed width on any element except `.parent` (width=300px) and `.square` (width=15px, height=15px). I want it to automatically/dynamically adjust to `.parent` container width.

Comment: maybe so? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fseu83gf/

Comment: If you are going to stick with vertical-align, remeber that it only works with display: table related rules. Otherwise, just remove it.

Comment: Why so much markup? You can do that with just a single `label`.

Comment: @madaaah `vertical-align` also works with `inline` elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: @Dmitriy - blue square is for example and there will be much more complicated element instead of it that can't be wrapped by `:before`.

Comment: @user606521 Your 15x15 `.square` can have other dimensions as well?

Comment: Hmm, I want it to dynamically adjust to `.parent` width (edited question). So it should work "as a function of `.parent` width)

Comment: such variant? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rys6tnpg/

Comment: Wow it seems that it works! @Hidden Hobbes answer also works for me but yours supports older browsers (IE9+ instead of IE10+) - please write answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes you're right! My bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `display: table`

```css
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    display: table;
}

.parent.error-frame {
    border-color: red;
}
.parent > div{
    display: table-cell;
}
.parent > div:nth-of-type(1){
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.square {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
     <div>
         <label class="label">Long label text, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</label>         
     </div>   
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
     <div>
         <label class="label">Long label text, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</label>         
     </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Just please remove max-width: 250px from .label class - it works without it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set a `max-width`. Since you're using set pixel widths, just set a `width` on the label class to whatever pixel width you need, in this case, 285px.

[Fiddle so you can see it.](https://jsfiddle.net/pb39hmdj/)

Comment: This does not work when parent is not 300px, as the OP stated. The 300px is just one example. He wants the label to occupy all the parent width.

Comment: I don't want to set any fixed width on any element but parent and square. That's the problem.

Comment: Ah. My apologies. @HiddenHobbes answer seems like it might be good for you then.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this layout by using `flexbox`:

- Add `display: flex;` to `.parent`, this tells its children to use the `flexbox` model
- Add `align-items: center;` to `.parent`, this will vertically align the children
- Add `flex: 1;` to `.label-without-max-width`, this will tell it to take up as much space as necessary

```css
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  border: solid 1px green;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
.parent.error-frame {
  border-color: red;
}
.square {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
.label {
  max-width: 250px;
}
.label-without-max-width {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <label class="label">Long label text, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</label>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent error-frame">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <label class="label label-without-max-width">Long label text, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</label>
</div>
```

Support for `flexbox` is pretty good (minus older versions of IE) http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Hey your answer works for me but Dimitri mentioned another approach (in comments) https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rys6tnpg/ which also works and AFAIK it has better browser support (IE9+ instead of IE10+ with flex)

Comment: No problem, @Dmitriy's solution is the way to go if you need older IE support. :)